# Convergence of a finite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, divergent-series

How do I write a converged form for the following finite series?
$\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}\frac{1}{k!}f(x)^k$ where M is any integer and x is variable
If the convergence of this series is not possible, is it possible to approximate it ??

Comment: Depends on $f(x)$, doesn't it? Any finite series will converge, after all

Comment: finite series are convergence or undefined. What do you mean by convergence?

Comment: Isn't that the $M-1$ term of the series expansion of $e^{f(x)}$?

Comment: @HamidShafieAsl If I take M-1=infinity, then above series can converge to e^f(x). Similarly, for finite M-1 terms, is the convergence of the above system possible?

Comment: @kunal He/She wrote that M is an integer!